# Wifi tethering blinks to ON/OFF mode while connecting the device to data

Tags: wi-fi, tethering

Wifi tethering shows an error while activating data on my android device. What may be the cause? Please reply. 
Thanks in advance.

*I am using Xiaomi phone, First of all I will switch on the tethering function on phone, and connect it to laptop. After that, I will connect the phone with internet. Then it shows the wifi tethering icon,and after some seconds it will goes to hidden state(turns-off tethering), again shows and hides, until data is off.*

Comment: Could be anything – depends on the error. Honestly: You didn't give us enough information to help you. Can you quote that error, or include a screenshot? While on it: a step-by-step description of what you're doing would be helpful as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In addition to Izzy's comment, `while connecting the device to data` -- What does this mean? How do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'**Android System**' system application which controls **tethering** feature if android phones. I had provided restriction to it unexpectedly. And **enabling** it for data usage, solved the problem.